# What does this raw property mean in v-for directive on vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I saw a code block on vuetify documentation but i don't really get why they use the raw property in v-card component? Is that a special property?

Can anyone help me understand that?

Thank you.

```
<v-data-iterator :items="items" :page="page">
  <template v-slot:default="{ items }">
    <template
      v-for="(item, i) in items"
      :key="i"
    >
      <v-card v-bind="item.raw"></v-card>

      <br>
    </template>
  </template>
</v-data-iterator>

export default {
  data: () => ({
    page: 1,
    items: Array.from({ length: 15 }, (k, v) => ({
      title: 'Item ' + v + 1,
      text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, ratione debitis quis est labore voluptatibus! Eaque cupiditate minima, at placeat totam, magni doloremque veniam neque porro libero rerum unde voluptatem!',
    })),
  }),
}
```

I checked this documentation but couldn't understand it.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-iterators/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a special property, it is just the item object.  The array `items` from `v-slot:default="{ items }"` is not the same `items` defined on your component, but it is based off of it.  Similarly, `item` is not a direct object from your defined `items` array, but it does *contain* the object, and is stored on the `raw` property.  You can verify this information yourself by console.logging or rendering the `items` array provided by the v-slot.

I took the example code from the Vuetify docs and rendered the `item` key-value pairs to the UI in [this Vuetify Playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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) so you can see what I mean.